# Running python service as background service

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, centos

Here is the python code, how can I start the application as a daemon using only `python 1.py` command?

```
import eventlet
from eventlet import wsgi



def hello_world(env, start_response):
    if env['PATH_INFO'] != '/':
        start_response('404 Not Found', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
        return ['Not Found\r\n']
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Hello, World!\r\n']

wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8090)), hello_world)
```

Comment: This isn't so much a python problem, your OS is in charge of starting processes. Which OS are you using?

Comment: Centos,But i dont want this on startup of machine.when i run this application it has to start as background process.

Comment: Would a cronjob suit your needs? _Info on it can be seen [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-autotasks.html)_. I know from personal experience running a python script in a cron job can be a pain. One approach to this is to create a bash script that calls your python script stating full paths to the file.

Comment: when i import daemon runner in python application will run the application as daemon ,but when i try with wsgi server  it i not happening.

Answer (score 1):

Supervisor is a great utility for managing long-running background processes.

Install [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/installing.html), create a configuration file that specifies the command you want to run, user who should run it, log locations, etc.

Then you can start up the service with sudo supervisorctl start {{ name }} and stop it as needed with a similar command.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to start a process in CentOS, chose yourself which one solves the problem in the way you prefer.

1. Open a terminal, run `python 1.py` and forget about it until you shut the machine down
2. Open a terminal, run `nohup python 1.py &` and close the terminal. Nohup keeps the program alive even though the session ended. If you need to kill it, you need to find it in the process list with `ps -ax` and kill it with `kill <process_id>`
3. Read the documentation on the [deamon](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/7/daemon/) function and call your script with it
4. I am sure there are many more